# Laravel xml Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-5, plesk

I am trying to get xml data from the plesk api with a script that works outside laravel.
But since I am trying to use this script in laravel I get an error on the second line below:

```
$xmlresponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo $xmlresponse->webspace->customer->get->result->id;
```

Error: Trying to get property of non-object

I think it is because of the object operator (->).
But I am not sure if blade has problems with this.

PS: $response contains xml data.

Comment: what are webspace, customer, get. result..?

Comment: It is XML data received from a packet:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and I feel dumb..
The correct package should've been:

```
$xmlresponse->customer->get->result->id;
```

instead of

```
echo $xmlresponse->webspace->customer->get->result->id;
```